# Program not doing what it should - C

Tags: c

I wrote a program that receive from user a series of numbers (<=20) while the last '0' means end of series (not included in series storing). 2 arrays (x,y) size 20 (0-19 + 1 for the '0') must be zeros, and m means number of organs in Y array.

The user must enter numbers ascending (it is ok 4ex. 1,2,2,3,7,8,...,0) and end with a '0' of course, if not, appropriate error message will appear, and program will shut off.

We can be sure the user will keep the <=20 numbers of input.

Y array will be (if everything went ok with X array) a sorted array of X but without duplicates. 'm' will be number of organs in Y exclude '0' of course.

Function SIFT must only organize the Y array for being printed from main().

**Example:**

If user will store in X: 1,1,2,3,5,5,5,6

On screen will be: m = 5 Y = 1,2,3,5,6

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int x[20] = {0} , y[20] = {0};
    int m=0,temp=0,curr=0,i=0,j=0;

    printf("Please enter your numbers now:\n\n");

    /*enter numbers one by one. if x[i+1] value < x[i] value, err msg.
      when user want to end the series he must enter '0' which means end of string (it wont       included in x[]) */
    while ( ( temp = getchar() ) != '0' )
    {
        if (temp >= curr)
        {
            x[i] = temp;
            curr = temp;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        }
    }

    SIFT(x,y);

    for (i=0 ; y[i]=='0' ; i++) /*strlen(y) without ('0')'s includes*/
        m++;

    /*Prints  m , y's organs*/
    printf("\n\nm = %d",m);
    printf("Y = ");
    while (y[j]!='0')
    {
        printf ("%d ,",y[j]);
        j++;
    }

return 0;
}

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (x_arr[i] != '0')
    {
        if (x_arr[i] == x_arr[i+1]) /*if current val. equals next val. -> jump dbl at x_arr*/
        {
            y_arr[j] = x_arr[i];
            i+=2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            y_arr[j]=x_arr[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }    

}
```

For some unknown reason, for any kind of legal input I'm getting a "The numbers are not at the right order..." error message...

I will be more than happy if someone can fix it so it should work properly, because until now I can see everything is seems to be OK.....

Thanks :( ...

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of `temp` and `curr`?

Comment: In the future, try creating a more descriptive title.  See titles of other questions for examples.

Answer (score 3):

`getchar()` does not do what you think it does. Read its description ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html ).

You can try `scanf()` instead ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html ), or better, `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the input parsing (with `scanf` for instance), your code still has some problems:

1) You assume input is ordered (but not strictly). Therefore you don't need to store everything in `x`, you could at input time only compare the previous number and the current number. if current number is GREATER than previous (strictly), you store it, and increase `m`. If it is LESSER than the previous, you must exit. If they are equal, do nothing:

```
while ( scanf("%d",&temp) == 1 && temp != 0 && m < 20) {
    if (temp > curr) {
        y[m++] = temp;
    }
    else if (temp < curr) {
        printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    curr = temp;
}
```

(therefore you don't need `SIFT` and the array `x` anymore).

2) You don't exit the program under the termination condition, you just print a message! (fixed above).

3) I put a `m < 20` condition at the loop, just to make sure no segfault would occur at misbehaved inputs.

That should put you on the track. Observe that now that you're using `scanf`, the termination condition is not a char anymore (`'0'`) but a number (`0`). And remember to `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top (for `exit()`)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using `getchar()` instead of something like `fgets()`. Are you pressing newline after input numbers?

Comment: No. The return value of scanf won't be '0' in the case where the input is a line containing "0".

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `getchar()` to read a number, it's purpose it's to read a single character from the input buffer!

You need to call `scanf()` or `fgets()`, for example.

Comment: **NO!** Don't use `gets()`. **NEVER USE `gets()`!** `gets()` is impossible to use safely. Use `fgets()` instead, and remove the trailing `'\n'` if needed.

Comment: @pmg you're right and I corrected, but since it's an homework I don't think `gets()` would cause big troubles.

Comment: That's the point! The OP is learning. We don't want him to even know `gets` exists (it will be gone from the next C Standard). Better to get him used to use `fgets()` from the start :)

Answer (score 0):

First, it would greatly help if you included in your Error Print statement the values of `temp` and `curr`.

Since others have said it, you do not want to read a char, you want to read a number.  The links pmg has provided in his answer should get you to a solution.  Also, debugging using breakpoints could have likely helped you identify this problem quick, I urge you to investigate some basic debugging skills.. Print Errors can only get you so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Also,

If I understood correct, I think you mean

```
for (i=0 ; y[i] != '0' ; i++) /* strlen */
    m++;
```