# Probably problem with scanning numbers - C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program not doing what it should - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664480/program-not-doing-what-it-should-c)

Hello,

Following program only read numbers from input and do stop when rull is violated, but 1 big problem is that it doesn't stop reading numbers and worse, don't print on screen what it should.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int x[20] = {0} , y[20] = {0};
    int m=0,temp=0,curr=0,i=0,j=0;

    printf("Please enter your numbers now:\n\n");

    /*enter numbers one by one. if x[i+1] value < x[i] value, err msg.
      when user want to end the series he must enter '0' which means end of string (it wont       included in x[]) */
    while ( (scanf("%d",&temp) ) != '0' )
    {
        if (temp >= curr)
        {
            x[i] = temp;
            curr = temp;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        }
    }

    SIFT(x,y);

    for (i=0 ; y[i]=='0' ; i++) /*strlen(y) without ('0')'s includes*/
        m++;

    /*Prints  m , y's organs*/
    printf("\n\nm = %d",m);
    printf("Y = ");
    while (y[j]!='0')
    {
        printf ("%d ,",y[j]);
        j++;
    }

return 0;
}

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (x_arr[i] != '0')
    {
        if (x_arr[i] == x_arr[i+1]) /*if current val. equals next val. -> jump dbl at x_arr*/
        {
            y_arr[j] = x_arr[i];
            i+=2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            y_arr[j]=x_arr[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }    

}
```

Please help me solve this problem...
thnx.

Comment: it's not the same question as the previous, although it's nearly the same code.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &temp)` "has 2 results". One such "result" is the return value of the function: 1 if everything ok; 0 or EOF otherwise. The other "result" (when 1 was returned) is the value in the variable `temp` (the value entered by the user). You need to check both "results" ... as in (very pseudo code) `if (scanf()==1) { if (temp==0) ...; }`

Answer (score 3):

As a first hint, `scanf` returns the number of items read, so the condition `(scanf("%d",&temp) ) != '0'` will only be hit if you read 48 items (the ASCII value of 0).  This isn't going to happen with that format specifier so that's why you've got the loop.

Comment: But I don't want to count number of organs, I need it to stop when '0' occur...